# Using RX TX pin

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, arduino-ide

Can i use pin RX TX on Arduino Uno as reguler pin ? .
For input and output pin , because two digital pin on my board doesn’t work . Thank’s

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? do you mean pins 0 and 1?
What can't digital pin 2 do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use those pins like regular digital pins on the Uno. They are numbered 0 and 1. That is... provided you do not try to use `Serial`.

Comment: and the component wired to this pins can interfere with sketch upload. and if one of this two stops working then no serial upload will be possible.

Comment: Oke , thank’s u so much